# Is there a number system base $a$ where $2018$ can be written as $\overline{21312}^{a}$ in it?

Tags: calculus, natural-numbers, number-systems

That's actually the whole question.

Is there a number system base $a$ where $2018$ can be written as $\overline{21312}^{a}$ in it?

I honestly don't know what I do more than this

$2a^4 + a^3 + 3a^2 + a = 2016$

I don't know how to solve an equation like this and how to check if it has solutions.

EDIT: It seems that the book forgot to mention it in the question but $a > 3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2a^4 + a^3 + 3a^2 + a + 2 = 2018$$
Since $a$ is positive:
$$2a^4 < 2016$$
$$a^4 < 1008$$
$$a < 5.6$$
Since $a$ is integer:
$$a <= 5$$
Now let's take $a = 5$:
$$2a^4 + a^3 + 3a^2 + a + 2 = 1452$$
If we take $a < 5$, we will get numbers less than 1452.

Means, there is no solution.

Comment: But why $2a^4 < 2016$? Why not $a^3 < 2016$ as an example?

Comment: The first term alone can't make the whole expression too large. So it must be less than $2016$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Okay makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that if you write $2018$ in base $a$ as $\overline{21312}^a$, then it leads to the following polynomial $2a^4+a^3+3a^2+a+2=2018$. Equivalently we have that we want an integer root of the polynomial $2a^4+a^3+3a^2+a-2016$. Now we can use the rational roots theorem to just check the divisors of $2016$. That is we must check if $a=1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,12,14,16,18,21,24,28,32,36,42,48,56,63,72,84,96,112,126,144,168,224,252,288,336,504,672,1008,2016$ are roots. Of which after checking them all none of them are roots.

Another solution would be to note that $a>3$, and just check $a=4,5,6,7$, and note that when $a=4$, $\overline{21312}^a=630$, when $a=5$ we have $\overline{21312}^a=1457$ when $a=6$ we have that $\overline{21312}^a=2924$, and as this polynomial is increasing for $a$ positive, we conclude that there is no solution.

Comment: Note: I realized my solution is wrong and am editing it.

Comment: What's rational roots theorem?

Comment: Rational roots theorem is a theorem saying (roughly) that if you have a polynomial with integer coefficients, then the integer roots must divide the constant term.

Comment: @TechnoKnight See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Well as $2131$ has more digits than $2018$, $a$ must be a base less than $10$.

And as $a$ divides $2a^4+a^3 + 3a^2 + a$ we must have $a| 2016= 2^5\cdot 3^2\times 7$ we must have only have $2,3,7$ as prime divisors.  So $a=2,4,8,3,6,9,7$.

Also $2016\div a = 2a^3 + a^2+3a + 1$.  But as $2^5|2016$ but none of $2,4,8,3,6,9,7$ have a power as high as $2^5$ dividing them, so $2016\div a$ must be even.  So $2a^3 + a^2+3a +1$ must be even.  But if $a$ is even then $2a^3+a^2 + 3a +1$ is odd and if $a$ is odd then $2a^3 + a^2 + 3a + 1$ is odd.  So no solutions are possible.

Answer (score 0):

$2a^4+a^3+3a^2+a \equiv 2016\pmod 2$
$a^3+a^2+a\equiv 0\pmod 2$
$a(a^2+a+1)\equiv 0\pmod 2$
$a^2+a+1$ is odd.
$a\equiv 0\pmod 2$
$2\mid a\implies 2^2\mid 2a^4+a^3+3a^2,2016\implies 2^2\mid a\implies 2^4\mid 2a^4+a^3+3a^2,2016\implies 2^4\mid a$
$a\geq 16\implies 2a^4+a^3+3a^2+a>2a^4\geq 2*16^4>2*10^4>2016$
contradiction
so $2a^4 + a^3 + 3a^2 + a = 2016$ has no positive integer solutions for $a$.